# I upgraded to Django 4.2.1 and django_plotly_dash is not working anymore - WrappedDash object has no attribute _generate_meta_html

Tags: django, docker, plotly-dash

django_plotly_dash docs says they now are compatible with 5x > Django > 3.2x, but after upgrading Django to 4.2.1, I can only make it work on local, but in production returns the traceback I share here below.

SETTINGS.PY

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'dpd_static_support',
    'channels', 
    'channels_redis'
    ...
]

PLOTLY_COMPONENTS = [
    'dash_core_components',
    'dash_html_components',
    'dash_renderer',
    'dpd_static_support',
    'dpd_components',
    'dash_bootstrap_components',
]

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

PLOTLY_DASH = {

    "ws_route" :   "dpd/ws/channel",
    "http_route" : "dpd/views",
    "http_poke_enabled" : True,
    "insert_demo_migrations" : False,
    "cache_timeout_initial_arguments": 60,
    "view_decorator": None,
    "cache_arguments": True,
    "serve_locally": False,
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
  'default': {
  'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
  'CONFIG': {
          'hosts': [('redis', 6379),], #ALSO TRIED USING 127.0.0.1
      },
  },
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'core.asgi.application' #Also tried using my custom routing
```

ROUTING.PY

```
from django_plotly_dash.routing import application
```

URLS.PY

```
from app import custom_dash_app

urlpatterns = [
...
path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
...
]
```

HTML

```
{% load plotly_dash %}

...
{% plotly_app_bootstrap name="custom_dash_app_name" aspect="16by9" %} <-- Also tried with direct and with plotly_app  name="" ratio=... -->
...
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
web_container |     raise exc_info[1]
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
web_container |     response = await get_response(request)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
web_container |     response = await wrapped_callback(
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 448, in __call__
web_container |     ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
web_container |     return await fut
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 22, in run
web_container |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 490, in thread_handler
web_container |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_container |   File "/aiterra_web_website/wallet/views.py", line 46, in walletHomepage
web_container |     return render(request, 'investing/wallet-homepage.html', context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
web_container |     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
web_container |     return template.render(context, request)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
web_container |     return self.template.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
web_container |     return self._render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
web_container |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
web_container |     return self.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
web_container |     return compiled_parent._render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
web_container |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
web_container |     return self.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
web_container |     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
web_container |     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
web_container |     return self.render(context)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 258, in render
web_container |     _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_plotly_dash/templatetags/plotly_dash.py", line 149, in plotly_direct
web_container |     resp = view_func()
web_container |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_plotly_dash/dash_wrapper.py", line 762, in index
web_container |     metas = self._generate_meta_html()
web_container | AttributeError: 'WrappedDash' object has no attribute '_generate_meta_html'
```

I already tried upgrading python to the most recent and stable version, but it did not work.

I managed to find the Wrapper thing here: https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/master/django_plotly_dash/dash_wrapper.py

The _generate_meta_html is where seems to be the problem... But not sure how to solve this issue so far.

```
def index(self, *args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        scripts = self._generate_scripts_html()
        css = self._generate_css_dist_html()
        config = self._generate_config_html()
        metas = self._generate_meta_html()
        renderer = self._generate_renderer()
        title = getattr(self, 'title', 'Dash')
        if self._favicon:
            import flask
            favicon = '<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{}">'.format(
                flask.url_for('assets.static', filename=self._favicon))
        else:
            favicon = ''

            _app_entry = '''
            <div id="react-entry-point">
                <div class="_dash-loading">
                   Loading...
                </div>
            </div>
        '''
        index = self.interpolate_index(
            metas=metas, title=title, css=css, config=config,
            scripts=scripts, app_entry=_app_entry, favicon=favicon,
            renderer=renderer)

        return index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue:

- python 3.11
- Django 3.2.20
- dash 2.11.1
- django-plotly-dash 2.2.2

```
django                    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django                    |   File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django                    |     response = get_response(request)
django                    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django                    |   File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
django                    |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django                    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django                    |   File "/home/app/app/eda_app/view_decorator.py", line 141, in wrapped_view
django                    |     return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
django                    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django                    |   File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_plotly_dash/views.py", line 115, in main_view
django                    |     resp = view_func()
django                    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^
django                    |   File "/home/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_plotly_dash/dash_wrapper.py", line 762, in index
django                    |     metas = self._generate_meta_html()
django                    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django                    | AttributeError: 'WrappedDash' object has no attribute '_generate_meta_html'
```

The problem is that `dash` does not have `_generate_meta_html` method in version `>2.10` (e.g. see [v2.9.3](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/v2.9.3/dash/dash.py#L857) and [v.2.10.0](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/v2.10.0/dash/dash.py)).

It is even mentioned in the [setup.py](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/v2.2.2/setup.py#L44) of the `django-plotly-dash` project that such a version is not supported (but not flagged as dependency conflict by using packages version manager on my end though).

**Solution**:

- install `dash>=2.0,<2.10`

I hope it helped :)